# Python write (iPhone) Emoji to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, emoji

I have been trying to write a simple script that can save user input (originating from an iPhone) to a text file. The issue I'm having is that when a user uses an Emoji icon, it breaks the whole thing.

OS: Ubuntu

Python Version: 2.7.3

My code currently looks like this

```
f = codecs.open(path, "w+", encoding="utf8")
f.write("Desc: " + json_obj["description"])
f.close()
```

When an Emoji character is passed in the description variable, I get the error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-8: ordinal not in range(128)

Any possible help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `json_obj["description"]` a `unicode`, or a `str`? If the latter, what encoding is it in? Also, can you `print repr(json_obj["description"])` right before the error, so we can see what you're actually trying to print?

Comment: Also, where does `json_obj` come from? The name implies the stdlib `json` module, but the fact that the keys and values are apparently `str` implies that it's not…

Answer (score 6):

The most likely problem here is that `json_obj["description"]` is actually a UTF-8-encoded `str`, not a `unicode`. So, when you try to `write` it to a `codecs`-wrapped file, Python has to decode it from `str` to `unicode` so it can re-encode it. And that's the part that fails, because that automatic decoding uses `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is `'ascii'`.

For example:

```
>>> f = codecs.open('emoji.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
>>> e = u'\U0001f1ef'
>>> print e

>>> e
u'\U0001f1ef'
>>> f.write(e)
>>> e8 = e.encode('utf-8')
>>> e8
'\xf0\x9f\x87\xaf'
>>> f.write(e8)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

There are two possible solutions here.

First, you can explicitly decode everything to `unicode` as early as possible. I'm not sure where your `json_obj` is coming from, but I suspect it's not actually the stdlib `json.loads`, because by default, that always gives you `unicode` keys and values. So, replacing whatever you're using for JSON with the stdlib functions will probably solve the problem.

Second, you can leave everything as UTF-8 `str` objects and stay in binary mode. If you know you have UTF-8 everywhere, just `open` the file instead of `codecs.open`, and write without any encoding.

---

Also, you should strongly consider using [`io.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead of `codecs.open`. It has a number of advantages, including:

- Raises an exception instead of doing the wrong thing if you pass it incorrect values.
- Often faster.
- Forward-compatible with Python 3.
- Has a number of bug fixes that will never be back-ported to `codecs`.

The only disadvantage is that it's not backward compatible to Python 2.5. Unless that matters to you, don't use `codecs`.